# while loading plugin vue-componen from package akyrum:vue-component, Cannot find module

Tags: meteor, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-meta

```
while loading plugin `vue-component` from package `akyrum:vue-component`: module.js:547:15: cannot find module
```

> the following error line shows
>   c:\users\appdata\local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.8.0\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\builtin\interoprequiredefault' at function.module._resolvefilename (module.js:547:15) at function.module._load (module.js:474:25) at module.require (module.js:596:17) at require (internal/module.js:11:18) at object.require (c:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2083:22) at makeinstalleroptions.fallback (packages/modules-runtime.js:653:18) at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:244:16) at tag-handler.js (:623:30) at fileevaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:339:7) at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16) at :2236:1 at :2243:3

Comment: when I'm going to run my app using meteor command in its directory that time it showing these.

Comment: You probably globally installed packages that are of a different version. Check your global node modules directory.

Comment: Show us how you're calling module.js.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy you right. but what should I do? already I renamed my global node-modules to node-modulesold. I'm describing for your better understand. Very first when I'm going to create a project by meteor that time it threw an error and I renamed the global node-mudules letter on it worked. after adding vue template its now showing the error when I want to run the project.

Comment: your guess is right before meteor I had installed node modules globally but what solution you would like to provide me. @Ohgodwhy

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and was able to resolve it based on the fix discussed [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10129):

Essentially, you need to create 2 symlinks:

- `@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin` => `@babel/runtime/helpers`
- `@babel/runtime/helpers/helpers/builtin` => `@babel/runtime/helpers`